# Calculate coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+bx^c)^d(1+ex^f)^g$

Tags: combinatorics

Given something like: Find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+bx^c)^d(1+ex^f)^g$ how would you approach it?

I know you use binomial series and negative binomial series to expand it but I usually get stuck soon after.

I'll show some of my attempts (I have no idea if they are correct):
$$[x^n](1+3x^2)^{-5} = {n+2\choose 4}*3^{n-2}$$

$$[x^5](1+3x^3)^3(1-x)^{-2} = 30$$